# How can I make the canvas item to fill the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I set the canvas's size in js:

```
const cv = document.getElementById("cv");
cv.width = innerWidth;
cv.height = innerHeight;
```

However, there are scroll bars apeared.
How can I deal with it? (without using `overflow: hidden`)

Comment: using `overflow: hidden` is the right answer, is there some reason you don't want to use that? -- but if you have padding and margins set to 0, you might avoid the scrollbars without hiding overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Using `overflow: hidden` is the correct and easiest code to place in your CSS.

```css
#cv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will remove the scrollbars.

---

However, if you want to avoid that code, you can set `padding` and `margin` to `0`, which will more or less have the same effect.

```css
#cv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

This will also remove the scrollbars, kind of like `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: The overflow would be in the parent element, which is not posted, but if the innerWidth and innerHeight are correct, (may not be the case). then 2nd part of your answer should work. ... css quirks mode for example gives bad widths.

Comment: Well, it seems that the 2nd part didn't work.... I don't know why...